# Basic question about meta tags with dynamic pages

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty unfamiliar with how meta tags work with dynamics pages so I thought I'd consult folks on here for help :-)

My site has dozens of dynamically generated pages (e.g. a bunch of tour pages). An admin can add & delete tours but on top of that they can also specify what meta tags they'd like to add to each specific tour.

For example, one page may get this info from my server

```
meta_tags: ['yosemite', 'tour']
tour_name: 'Yosemite tour'
pics: ['image1', 'image2']
tour_description: 'This is a yosemite tour'
```

With that info, I set the meta tags using something like

`$('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'new Meta Description here')`

If I'm dynamically generating the pages based on the info given from the admin, will the meta tags be picked up for SEO purposes? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

In general, if you're adding meta tags client-side, most crawlers will not see them.  Most crawlers will only make an HTTP request and parse the HTML as returned by the server.

However, *some* crawlers ([including Google... sometimes](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/fix-search-javascript)) will actually execute JavaScript and scrape the DOM out of the page.

If you feel that these tags are critical for SEO, you should make sure they're output by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags are snippets of text that helps search engine crawlers to understand your website page contents. present-day google gives very less attention for meta keywords and meta descriptions tags with respect to the SEO. But meta description tag helps to generate search engine snippet when your page appears in Google or other search engines results.

My idea is if admin provides the meta keywords and descriptions, it's better to add
this information to your web page.

```
let description = "";
if(isAdminProvideDesc){
  description = "Admin provided description"
}else{
  description = "Default page description"
}

$('meta[name=description]').attr('content', description)
```

[see the image how description meta tag helps search engines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBTRi.png)